# ‘Error: junk at end of line’ with native-comp

Tags: microsoft-windows, native-comp

I recently switched to Emacs 28.1 hoping to use the new native-comp support. Being on Windows, I followed [these instructions](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/skyr49/alphagnuorg_has_shiny_new_emacs_28091_windows/hvpgq5f/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) to install libgccjit, copying the resulting `libgccjit.dll` library to Emacs’s `bin` folder. However, upon doing so, I received the following warning whenever Emacs attempted to compile any file:

```
Warning (comp): C:\Users\<omitted>\AppData\Local\Temp\\libgccjit-554575/fake.s:4: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `"' Disable showing Disable logging
Warning (comp): C:\Users\<omitted>\AppData\Local\Temp\\libgccjit-554575/fake.s:4: Error: file number less than one Disable showing Disable logging
Warning (comp): c:\emacs\bin\libgccjit-0.dll: error: error invoking gcc driver Disable showing Disable logging
Warning (comp): <filename>: Error: Internal native compiler error failed to compile Disable showing Disable logging
```

(Where `<filename>` is the name of each file Emacs attempted to compile, of course.)

Curiously, when I launch Emacs from MSYS2 MinGW (64-bit), the errors disappear, and Emacs is successfully able to compile all files. What is going on here, and how may I fix it? All I know at this point is that the problem is probably unrelated to the dependencies to `libgccjit.dll`: using `dumpbin libgccjit.dll /dependents` revealed that Emacs’s `bin` folder already contains all dependencies of `libgccjit.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have another msys2/MinGW environment in your path? I had the same error message and after removing the bin folder of [git-sdk-64](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git-sdk-64) from my path, emacs could compile the files.

A binary or library which is not found should trigger an error message about a missing dependency.

*Sorry to write this here as answer, I don't have enough reputation to comment.*

Comment: I do not have any MSYS2/MinGW environment in my path. However, it turns out I *do* have several other instances of `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll`! I assume that different versions of these are messing up everything — when I get some time I’ll try rearranging my PATH to see what happens.

Comment: I finally got some time to try this; alas, it doesn’t seem to work. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Actually, on further investigation, the problem does indeed turn out to be closely related to what you suggested: Emacs was trying to run processes like `as` and `ld`, but didn’t know where to find them. So the problem was not one of too *many* conflicting files on PATH, but too *few*. I’m not quite sure how to solve this, though, short of adding the whole MinGW64 environment to my PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `C:\msys2\mingw64\bin` to your windows path using the "Edit System Environment Variables" control panel.

While other approaches are possible I haven't found any that is simpler, nor has this caused any issue for me.  In any case, copying `libgccjit.dll` into the `bin` folder of your Emacs installation is not sufficient to get [native elisp compilation](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GccEmacs) working.

Irrespective of DLLs directly needed by `libgccjit.dll`, invoking just-in-time compilation implies running GCC. This, in turn, requires that GCC can find your system (e.g. MSYS2) configuration, for example [environment variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/internals/index.html#environment-variables) settings up your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  By using `libgccjit.dll` from its installation location you preserve this configuration as captured when you installed `libgccjit`.

When you launch from MSYS2's MinGW64 shell the relevant bin folder has already been added to your path for you.